# How to prove $(a \cdot b)^n = a^n \cdot b^n$?

Tags: exponentiation

Assuming $a, b \in \{\mathbb{R^-,R^+}\}$ and $n \in \mathbb{R}$.
We often see the statement:
$$(a \cdot b)^n = a^n \cdot b^n$$

Why we get the statement? 
How to prove this?

---

There should pay attention, the $n \in \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You can prove it for $n\in\Bbb N$ using commutativity of multiplication and induction

Comment: you mean $a,b>0$?

Comment: It does not make sense to write that $a,b\in \{\mathbb{R}^- ,\mathbb{R}^+ \}$.

Comment: for avoid $0^0$

Comment: With that you would be saying that $a=\mathbb{R}^-$ or $a=\mathbb{R}^+$. Similarly for $b$. Better you could just write $a\neq 0$.

Comment: You probably want $a > 0$ and $b > 0$. Raising a negative number to the power of a rational is dicey enough without worrying about real powers.

Comment: Similar question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12720/why-is-xn-cdot-xm-xnm?rq=1

Comment: Again, for $a<0\land b<0$ the claim fails. It works for $(a<0\land b>0)\lor (a>0\land b<0)\lor(a>0\land b>0)\lor n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: why for <0∧<0 it claim fails?

Answer (score 1):

For any $a>0$, is defined $a^x=e^{x\log a}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So
$$(ab)^x=e^{x\log (ab)}=e^{x(\log a +\log b)}=e^{x\log a}\cdot e^{x\log b}=a^xb^x$$
The assumption $a, b> 0$ is clearly necessary for this to be true.

Comment: The $log$ is based on $exponent$, so I don't think this can prove it.

Comment: Everything depends on your definitions, for example, you can define $$\log x:=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$$ for all $x>0$. With this, prove that $\log(xy)=\log(x)+\log(y)$. And finally, you define $a^x=e^{x\log a}$ for any $a>0$ (all this with the purpose that things work as they should).

Comment: Of course it's not the only way to prove it, but it's still correct, again, it all depends on your definitions.

Comment: @244boy Just have a think about defining real powers. We have a natural definition for $a^n$ where $n \in \Bbb{N}$. We can extend it to $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ (where $a \neq 0$) using multiplicative inverses, and further into $n \in \Bbb{Q}$, by using roots. How would we define $a^\pi$? Bear in mind, you can't define it to be what your calculator says, as your calculator also needs a definition to display anything (plus, it only displays an approximation).

Comment: @244boy A naive (but viable) approach would be to define $a^\pi$ as a limit of $a^{r_n}$ where $r_n \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $r_n \to \pi$, but there's much to prove here, including that $a^{r_n}$ has a limit and that it doesn't depend on the choice of $r_n$. The more modern approach is to define $e^x$ or $\ln$ first (as some kind integral, limit, power series, etc; there are a lot of options) and define $a^x$ as Azif00 does in their answer.