# Why Does $a^0 = 1$ and $a^{-p} = {\frac{1}{a^p}}$ if $(a \not = 0) , p \not= 0$?

Tags: exponentiation

Why does $a^0 = 1$ and $a^{-p} = {\frac{1}{a^p}}$ if $(a \not = 0)$ and $p \not= 0$?

How can we prove these formulas?

Comment: Are you looking for formal proofs or intuitions about why these statements are true?

Comment: Based on your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279408/how-to-prove-a-cdot-bn-an-cdot-bn), is $p$ supposed to be in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{ 0\}$? Also, $a^{-p} = \frac{1}{a^p}$, not $a^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

Comment: I think of $a^0$ like an empty product, which is $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an intuition test of why the properties should be defined like this:

The fundamental property of the exponential functions is the following:
$b^x\cdot b^y=b^{x+y}$.

The other properties are derived in such a way that the mentioned property is satisfied. 
For example: since we want the equation to be fulfilled
$$b^0\cdot b^x=b^{0+x}=b^x$$
we must define $b^0:=1$.
Since we want the following equation to be fulfilled
$$b^{-x}\cdot b^x=b^{-x+x}=b^0=1$$
we must define $b^{-x}:=1/b^x$. Since we want the following equation to be fulfilled
$$\underbrace{b^{1/n}\cdot b^{1/n}\cdots b^{1/n}}_{n\, \textrm{factors}}=b^1=b$$
we must define $b^{1/n}:=\sqrt[n]{b}$. Similarly, we must to define $b^{m/n}:=(\sqrt[n]{b})^m.$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^{0} = a^{n-n} = \frac{a^{n}}{a^{n}} = 1$$

Also,

Do you mean

$$ a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^{n}}? $$